# What is an example of a non-socket.io process?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am going through the [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Sending-messages-from-the-outside-world) and the docs say that you need to use [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter) to communicate with socket.io servers easily from non-socket.io processes.

What is an example of a non-socket.io process?

Comment: I guess It means any TCP client that is not using socket.io. Written with C#, Java, Python etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use socket.io in a bidirectional communication application, the method of implementation is that you create the socket.io server in your back end and a socket.io client in your front end. The socket.io process mimics a state-full connection between the server and the client until the disconnection happens.

Now, what if you want to emit events in the server from outside this connection?

socket.io-emitter is the socket.io way of making this possible.

```
const io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 });
io.emit('outsider-ready', 'foo');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still son't quite understand. What is an example of how I would use this if I am creating a chat app? What is an example of  emitting events in the server from outside this connection?

Comment: That is only a use case.